# simple CSV parser (C++) to deal with commas inside quotes

Tags: c++, csv

Seems to be a perenial issue, CSVs. In my case, I have data like this:

```
"Incident Number","Incident Types","Reported Date","Nearest Populated Centre"
"INC2008-008","Release of Substance","01/29/2008","Fort Nelson"
"INC2008-009","Release of Substance, Adverse Environmental Effects","01/29/2008","Taylor"
```

I built a parser that makes it into a lovely `vector<vector<string>>`:

```
string message = "Loading CSV File...\n";
genericMessage(message);
vector<vector<string>> content;
vector<string> row;
string line, word, block;

vector<string> incidentNoVector;

fstream file(fname, ios::in);
if (file.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        row.clear();

        stringstream str(line);

        while (getline(str, word, ','))
            row.push_back(word);
        content.push_back(row);
    }
}
else
    cout << "Could not open the file\n";
```

but didn't notice the extra comma in some of the data (row 3). Any ideas? I've already built a huge amount of code based on the original `vector<vector<string>>` expected output, so I really can't afford to change that.

Once I've gotten the vector, I strip the first line out (the header) and place it in it's own object, then put all the remaining rows in a separate object that I can call using `[][]`.

```
        // Place the header information in an object, then remove it from the vector
Data_Headers colHeader;
colHeader.setColumn_headers(content[0]);
content.erase(content.begin());

// Place the row data in an object.
Data_Rows allData;
allData.setColumn_data(content);

Row_Key incidentNumbers;
for (int i = 0; i < allData.getColumn_data().size(); i++)
{
    incidentNoVector.push_back(allData.getColumn_data()[i][0]);
}
incidentNumbers.setIncident_numbers(incidentNoVector);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: look at std::quoted.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a ready CSV parser library you could create a class that stores the values in one row and overload `operator>>` for that class. Use [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) when reading the individual fields in that operator.

Example:

```
struct Eater { // A class mainly used for eating up commas in an istream
    char ch;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const Eater& e) {
    char ch;
    if(is.get(ch) && ch != e.ch) is.setstate(std::istream::failbit);
    return is;
}

struct Row {
    std::string number;
    std::string types;
    std::string date;
    std::string nearest;
};

// Read one Row from an istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Row& r) {
    Eater comma{','};
    is >> std::quoted(r.number) >> comma >> std::quoted(r.types) >> comma
       >> std::quoted(r.date) >> comma >> std::quoted(r.nearest) >> Eater{'\n'};
    return is;
}

// Write one Row to an ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Row& r) {
    os << std::quoted(r.number) << ',' << std::quoted(r.types) << ','
       << std::quoted(r.date) << ',' << std::quoted(r.nearest) << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

After you've opened the file, you could then create and populate a `std::vector<Row>` in a very simple way:

```
    Row heading;
    if(file >> heading) {
        std::vector<Row> rows(std::istream_iterator<Row>(file),
                              std::istream_iterator<Row>{});
        // All Rows are now in the vector
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zTe3Khahb)